# how to treat dependent objects (not sure how to phrase this)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm learning TDD and rails. I'm hurting myself to a "logic" problem. Let me first present a situation.

We have 3 Models: `Project`, `Mission`, `Attachment`. I created them like this

```
rails g model Mission
rails g model Project
rails g model Attachment title:string attachable:references{polymorphic}
rake db:migrate
```

What generates this `schema.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180307200338) do
  create_table "attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "attachable_type"
    t.integer "attachable_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["attachable_type", "attachable_id"], name: "index_attachments_on_attachable_type_and_attachable_id"
  end
  create_table "missions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

For the models, we have this:

```
# app/models/mission.rb
class Mission < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
end

# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable
end

# app/models/attachment.rb
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now we have the context, I would like to introduce my "logic" problem. For me it is totally logic to create an `Attachment` like this:

```
Mission.find(1).attachments.create(file: 'my-file.jpg')
Project.find(1).attachments.create(file: 'my-file.jpg')
```

But it is difficult to imagine myself creating an attachment like this:

```
Attachment.create(attachable: Mission.find(1))
Attachment.create(attachable: Project.find(1))
```

Before starting TDD, I never thought about that. I always used the first method and that's it. But now I'm writing my test for my Attachment model and I end up doing stuff like:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AttachmentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "should be valid" do
    resource = build(:attachment)
    assert resource.valid?
  end

  # FIXME is 'attachable' the final name?
  test "should require attachable" do
    resource = build(:attachment, attachable: nil)
    assert resource.invalid?
  end

  test "should require file" do
    resource = build(:attachment, file: nil)
    assert resource.invalid?
  end
end
```

Somehow, I'm testing scenarios that will never happened `build(:attachment)`.

So my question: should I resign to think "I have to do it in order to prove `Project.attachments.build()` is gonna work" ?

I'm as well testing in `Project` and `Mission` stuff like:

- Should have many attachments
- Should allow attachment creation
- Should save attachment
- Should retrieve attachment

This is becoming confusing.

In terms of test, how should this relations be tested?

Sorry for the long an (maybe) a bit confusing post.

edit

**Question bonus** is there a way to simply say "we can not create from Attachment and have to go through a relation"

Comment: Yes, but you should make your assertions much more explicit as `assert resource.invalid?` will give a false positive if any other validation failed. You want to do something like `assert_includes "some error message",  resource.errors[:some_field]`. The inverse is also true - for the valid case you want to test the the key is not present in the errors hash.

Comment: Whether you really need to unit test the assocation at this level is debateable. You could just test that the join works as properly which would test it indirectly.

Comment: @max I got your concerns about the asserting only the `valid?`method. It's a bit out of the scope of the question but to address that (and to let you correct me if I'm wrong): The reason an `assert` is enough is because I start each test file with a test `should be valid` that test if the base Factory is valid. When I then test a required field, I always take the valid Factory to which I only change the required field. Therefore, the test can fail only because of this field.

Comment: Right but as a unit test its kind of worthless since there are so many other moving parts needed for it not to give false positives / negatives. Trust me, I have gotten burned on this exact issue before.

Comment: Will change then

Comment: @DanielCosta Tests should not be order dependent. But if you want to do this => https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/MiniTest/Unit/TestCase/i_suck_and_my_tests_are_order_dependent!/class

Comment: I agree with @max that you should not test `record.valid?`. For example, if you add a new column, like `description`, and validate its presence + remove the presence validation on `file` but you forget to update the factory accordingly, then your test `should require a file` will still pass even though it fails for a totally different reason. If you are using Rails 5, there is the very neat `record.errors.details` that would allow you to do `assert_includes record.errors.details[:file], {error: :blank}`. We actually implemented `details` in Rails 4 because it enable very precise testing

Comment: You are both right, I’m gonna change to assert the inclusion of .errors.details. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you are trying to test features built in rails:

- *Should have many attachments* = test `has_many :attachments`
- *Should allow attachment creation* = test`accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments`
- *Should save attachment* = test `autosave` of `has_many`
- *Should retrieve attachment* = test `has_many :attachments` again

Also, you said it yourself:

> Somehow, I'm testing scenarios that will never happened `build(:attachment)`.

So why bother?

---

You want to tests your objects to ensure they respond to *specs*. For example, if you want to make sure an `Attachment` *must have* an `attachable`, then you could write:

```
test 'must have attachable' do
  attachment = Attachment.new.tap(&:valid?)
  assert_includes(attachment.errors.details[:attachable], { error: :blank })
end
```

And this is, *I think*, the best option to ensure you have put a presence validation on an attribute.

Comment: So if get it well, I shouldn’t test if I have the has-many in projects and missions? Instead test the fact I can crest an attachment from attachment-test.rb?

Comment: Where I’m lost in your exemple is the fact I’m testing attachment while doing a new and valid on it. And I know in real scenarios, I’ll ALWAYS create an attachment through projects.attachments.create(file...)

Comment: The `attachment_test.rb` Test Class should define _tests_ to ensure the `Attachment` model responds to your _specs_, like for example validate the presence of the `attachable`, `file`, and other. You know that you will never do `Attachment.create(...)`, but where would you put that "ensure attachable is mandatory" test? in every test class of a Model which `has_many :attachable`? This seems overkill to test something several times (IMO)

Comment: So in the end the answer to your question _should I resign to think "I have to do it in order to prove Project.attachments.build() is gonna work"?_ would be yes, the Project test class should not be responsible for testing the behavior of an associated object. @DanielCosta

Comment: This makes sense. I get what you saying. I’m this case, should I test the has many relation? If I follow your logic I simply test if it’s respond to attachments but doesn’t test the behavior of attachments relation.

Comment: in a more direct way, how would you write a test to ensure your model has a relation (has one, has many or even belongs to)?

Comment: @DanielCosta you can test the existence of the association but I would not do it, simply because you won't remove the `has_many :attachments` without knowing what you do (and probably without breaking Integration tests also). But if you still want to do it, then maybe `assert(Project.reflections[:attachments]&.macro == :has_many, "Project model does not have a relation has_many :attachments")`.

Comment: @DanielCosta I see that you seem to be following the TDD way. I would suggest you to read this post (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98485/tdd-negative-experience).